# Spring: Fail to catch the thrown exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

I have the following negative test code (needs to fail and throw an exception):

```
@Test
public void testInventoryControllerGetNonExistingRegion() {

    final String name = "ME_2";
    RegionConfiguration refRegionConfiguration = prepareReferenceObject(name);

    try(
        inventoryRegionController.get(null,name);
    } catch (EntityDoesNotExistException e){

        //report something...
    }
}
```

The test calls the following method get() and SHOULD throw an EntityDoesNotExistException object.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get a region")
@RequestMapping(value = "regions/{" + REGION + "}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RegionConfiguration get(@RequestHeader(value = AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, defaultValue = "Bearer {{JWT}}") String authorization,
                               @PathVariable(REGION) String regionName) throws EntityDoesNotExistException {

    InventoryRegionEntity inventoryRegionEntity = null;
    inventoryRegionEntity = RegionInventoryService.find(regionName);

    if(null != inventoryRegionEntity)
        return RegionConfigurationMapper.mapInventoryRegionEntity(inventoryRegionEntity);
    else
        throw new EntityDoesNotExistException(InventoryRegionEntity.class, regionName);
}
```

The get() method **DOES THROW** the exception as required (I had a breakpoint and verified)!
But my test never catches it. And that is becuase what I get is an

```
HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
```

And this exception is really being caught by the catch clause.
Why is that happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that Spring does some durty work for you. In this particular case your exception will be enveloped to HTTP error, because REST is just an approach. Since you don't have any configuration about exception mapping, server will translate it to HTTP 500 - Server error. I think the best way for you to do the test is

```
@Test
public void testInventoryControllerGetNonExistingRegion() {
    final String name = "ME_2";
    RegionConfiguration refRegionConfiguration = prepareReferenceObject(name);

    try(
        inventoryRegionController.get(null,name);
        Assert.fail(); // don't forget to fail your test in no exception thrown
    } catch (HttpServerErrorException e){
        Assert.notNull(e);
        Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof EntityDoesNotExistException);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sergey thanks. Unfortunately, the assertTrue crashed on java.lang.AssertionError

Comment: @dushkin this means that cause of your exception is different from expected. If you will post full exception I can help you to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityDoesNotExistException` is the exception **on the server side**.
When you call your code via REST, the exception on the server side is translated to a JSON string, returned to the client side as an HTTP response with that JSON string in the body, and then converted back to a (different) exception **on the client side**, depending on the REST framework you are using. (In your case: `HttpServerErrorException`).

Comment: Thanks Yoav. So you explained to me what happens. But is there something I can do to catch this specific exception, or must I catch only "Exception"

Comment: You can catch HttpServerErrorException.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the exception you could use this code, I think is cleaner and avoid to use try/catch inside your test

```
@Test(expected = HttpServerErrorException.class) 
public void testInventoryControllerGetNonExistingRegion() {
    final String name = "ME_2";
    RegionConfiguration refRegionConfiguration = prepareReferenceObject(name);
    inventoryRegionController.get(null,name);
}
```

Comment: Seems like author is interested in confirmation of cause, because generally HttpServerErrorException can be returned in vast of cases.

Comment: Thanks cralfaro. This one I know. The question is how to catch the original exception...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is as follows:

```
try{

   //something...

}catch(HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Context context = null;
            try {
                context = objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), Context.class);
            } catch (IOException ioExc) {
                ioExc.printStackTrace();
            }
            assertEquals("Failed on ", context.getType(), ExceptionFromServer.class.getTypeName());
        }
```